# Unable to access push notification when app is in background for iOS 10

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

For iOS 8 and 9, when the application is in the background, when a push notification is received, I am able to store the information it in the app. But for iOS 10, I cannot retrieve the information when the app is in the background. But only if I open/click on the notification, userNotification centerDidReceiveNotificationResponse is invoked.

For iOS 8 & 9, this works fine.

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    // iOS 10 will handle notifications through other methods

    if( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO( @"10.0" ) )
    {
        NSLog( @"iOS version >= 10. Let NotificationCenter handle this one." );
        // set a member variable to tell the new delegate that this is background
        return;
    }
    NSLog( @"HANDLE PUSH, didReceiveRemoteNotification: %@", userInfo );

    // custom code to handle notification content

    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
    else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {
        NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" );
        completionHandler( UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData );
    }
}
```

For iOS 10 the method is not invoked,

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
    NSLog( @"Handle push from foreground" );
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    NSLog( @"Handle push from background or closed" );
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
}
```

Comment: enable Remote Notification in background modes capabilities

Comment: @KevinMac I have enabled

Comment: have you configured the UNUserNotificationCenter and its delegate? @Sharon

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;  . Delegate gets called while tapping on the notification but not in background.

Comment: add this peice of code:

[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
   if( !error ){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
  }];

Comment: any updates on `ios16` to receive foreground

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have follow Below Steps.

**Step 1 :** Import "**UserNotifications**" framework.

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
```

**Step 2 :** And your AppDelegate confirming "**UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**" delegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

**Step 3 :** For iOS10, You can ask for the permission like this

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
     if(!error){
         // Permission for notifications is granted. Do the other code
     }
 }];
```

> Now I think the problem you are having in your code in **Handling
>   delegate methods for UserNotifications**.

```
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}
```

Your code is missing below line of codes

```
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
```

And

```
    completionHandler();
```

In **willPresentNotification** and **didReceiveNotificationResponse** respectively.

Comment: I have added completion handler code but still the method is not called

Comment: `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);` does not working on `ios 16` any idea on this